# How to sed only a piece of text?

Tags: sed

Say I have a file with 2 rows, named *file.txt*:

```
Row 1: 80 is a nice number
Row 2: 80 is a cool number
Row 3: 80 is a piquant number
Row 4: 80 is a sexy number
```

I did `sed -i 's/80/8080/g'`, but by mistake I ran it twice and the result in all rows was `80808080` instead of just `8080`.

---

I believe it is most likely impossible in the common technology but I still want to ask if maybe, there is a sophisticated way to make `sed` do it's effect only once on this file. I mean, some kind of "lock" that will avoid happening of such mistakes like running this `sed` more than one time one the file, until I remove tat lock. This might (and I emphasis the word "might") be helpful when dealing with much longer rows, especially in large amounts.

It's not really a problem and I should avoid such a mistake and that's it, but I am curious to know if someone try to develop some technical "defense mechanism" from such `sed` mistakes.

Note: I believe a similar solution could be helpful to `awk` users as well.

Comment: don't use `-i` until you're sure?

Comment: aren't there 4 lines/rows in the sample file?

Comment: don't use /g unless you want every match in the line changed

Comment: This is a training / experience problem, not a technical problem. If you don't want to run `sed` twice, then be careful enough to not run it twice.

Comment: You could write the regex so that it doesn't match the result of its own substitution - e.g. using word boundaries `s/\b80\b/8080/`

Comment: Use version control.

Comment: `sed -i '/8080/!s/80/8080/g'` will work only on lines that do not yet contain `8080`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `-i` for in-place editing, especially if you're trying something out or developing some script.  Instead, always write to a temporary file.  Then check the file to see if it's ok, and possibly replace the original file with it.

The `-i` option is non-standard and is horribly non-portable between `sed` implementations.

The portable way to change a file using `sed` is

```
sed 'expression' file >newfile && mv newfile file
```

---

`awk` does not have the same issue. None of GNU `awk`, `mawk` or `nawk` supports in-place editing (which that isn't really something one often wants to do with `awk` anyway), so the problem of accidentally running the same `awk` script over a file twice (and getting twice the "effect" of editing the file) very seldom arises.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't very sophisticated, but it is a sort of a defense mechanism, when substituting a string with a string that contains itself is to add the previous and/or next characters to prevent duplicate substitution.

Per your example above I recommend something like one (or both) of the following:

- `sed -i 's/ 80 / 8080 /g'`
- `sed -i 's/^80 /8080 /g'`

Also, be careful with `-i` :)